# Adding Reply-To header using Mail API

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm trying to add a reply-to header using the Mail API in my google app engine. Right now I have the following but I am not quite sure how to get the custom headers in there. Could anyone help me out?

This is what I have as of now:

```
use \google\appengine\api\mail\Message;

try
{
  $message = new Message();
  $message->setSender("from@email.com");
  $message->addTo("to@email.com");
  $message->setSubject('Title');
  $message->setHtmlBody('Hi');
  $message->setTextBody('Hi');
  $message->send();
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
  echo "error";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$message->setReplyTo("replyto@email.com");`.
Check line 320 in [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/googleappengine/python/+/200fcb767bdc358a3acb5cf7cad1376fe69f12c5/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/mail/BaseMessage.php).

Note that emails are also accepted like this `"Reply To Name <replyto@email.com>"`

Comment: Thank you! And yes I noticed that thanks for the tip. I had just dumbed it down for the sake of my example.